# Install setuptools 1.4 into private copy of Python 3.3.3

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, python-3.3

I have installed a private copy of Python 3.3.3 on Ubuntu 13.10 in a directory under my home directory. I then use the following command to try and install setuptools into my private copy with the results shown below.

```
jonathan@Hades:~/Downloads/Python/setuptools$ ../Python-3.3.3/python ez_setup.py
Extracting in /tmp/tmpyx2c9o
Now working in /tmp/tmpyx2c9o/setuptools-1.4
Installing Setuptools
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/test-easy-install-6699.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

I also tried the --user option which allowed the install to complete but put the contents under my `~/.locals` directory, and not where I expected in the site-packages directory of my private Python installation.

I had thought that my private copy of Python would take care of finding the right site-packages directory but obviously this did not happen. What do I need to do to get a successful installation?

Comment: I am trying to install into a sub-directory of my home directory so sudo should be unnecessary as well as possibly setting incorret ownership in my private area.

Comment: It seems like it checks for writing permissions in `/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages` - thats why I ask. What is an successful installation to you?

Comment: A successful installation is when setuptools is installed into the Lib/site-packages directory of my private Python 3.3.3 installation. This is the first step in the process of creating a virtual environment with virtualenv, but I need setuptools and pip before I get virtualenv.